# C# Nest/Elasticsearch - Create index with analysis not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am fairly new to ElasticSearch and NEST, and i have run into an issue.

I am in the middle of trying to add analyzers and tokenizers, so that I can search substrings in my code.

Example:

```
User user1 = new User(){ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Boat", Number="45678" }
User user2 = new User(){ FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "Johansen", Number="123456" }
```

Searching "12345" yields user2, "456" yields user1 & user2, "Joh" yields user1 & user2, etc.

However when trying to add analyzers and tokenfilters to my settings when creating the index, they are not getting saved in the elastic database.

This works:

```
client.Indices.Create("customers",
                index => index
                .Settings(se => se
                        .Setting("index.mapping.total_fields.limit", "2000"))
                .Map<Customer>(x => x.AutoMap())
            );
```

This does not work:

```
client.Indices.Create("crmleads",
                index => index
                .Settings(se => se
                    .Analysis(a => a
                        .Analyzers(analyzer => analyzer
                            .Custom("substring_analyzer", analyzerDescriptor => analyzerDescriptor
                                .Tokenizer("standard")
                                .Filters("lowercase", "substring")))
                        .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                            .NGram("substring", filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor
                                .MinGram(2)
                                .MaxGram(15))))
                    .Setting("index.mapping.total_fields.limit", "2000"))
                .Map<CRMLead>(x => x
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(f => f.Name)
                            .Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(f => f.CVRNumber)
                            .Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))
                        .Boolean(t => t
                            .Name(f => f.IsConverted))
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(f => f.ContactPersonName)
                            .Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(f => f.ContactPersonEmail
                            ).Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))))
            );
```

Also the command line for the ElasticSearch server does not show any errors:

[Command line for ElasticSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOAwg.png)

[Created indexes shown in Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awlkP.png)

Also i have not added anything to my model classes:

```
public class CRMLead
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public string CVRNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string ContactPersonName { get; set; }
        public string ContactPersonEmail { get; set; }
        public string ContactPersonPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string PhaseOneDescription { get; set; }
        public CustomerContact CustomerContact { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Seller { get; set; }
        public CRMLeadStatus CRMStatus { get; set; }
        public List<UploadedFile> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
        public bool IsConverted { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public bool IsSold { get; set; }
    }
```

Full Code here:

```
public static void AddElasticsearch(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var url = configuration["Elasticsearch:url"];

            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url));

            AddDefaultMappings(settings);

            settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(f => f);

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);

            CreateIndices(client);

        }

private static void AddDefaultMappings(ConnectionSettings settings)
        {
            settings
                .DefaultMappingFor<ApplicationUser>(m => m
                    .IndexName("users")
                    .Ignore(au => au.AccessFailedCount)
                    .Ignore(au => au.Address)
                    .Ignore(au => au.AppInstalled)
                    .Ignore(au => au.BirthDay)
                    .Ignore(au => au.BorrowedEquipment)
                    .Ignore(au => au.ConcurrencyStamp)
                    .Ignore(au => au.CostPrice)
                    .Ignore(au => au.Culture)
                    .Ignore(au => au.CustomUserfields)
                    .Ignore(au => au.EmailConfirmed)
                    .Ignore(au => au.HireDate)
                    .Ignore(au => au.IceRelatives)
                    .Ignore(au => au.Id)
                    .Ignore(au => au.Initials)
                    .Ignore(au => au.IsCompanyOwner)
                    .Ignore(au => au.LastLogin)
                    .Ignore(au => au.LockoutEnabled)
                    .Ignore(au => au.LockoutEnd)
                    .Ignore(au => au.NormalizedEmail)
                    .Ignore(au => au.NormalizedUserName)
                    .Ignore(au => au.PasswordHash)
                    .Ignore(au => au.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                    .Ignore(au => au.PrivateEmail)
                    .Ignore(au => au.PrivatePhoneNumber)
                    .Ignore(au => au.ProfileImagePath)
                    .Ignore(au => au.SecurityStamp)
                    .Ignore(au => au.TwoFactorEnabled)
                    .Ignore(au => au.UploadedFile)
                )
                .DefaultMappingFor<CRMLead>(m => m
                    .IndexName("crmleads")
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.Address)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.City)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.Company)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.ContactPersonPhoneNumber)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.Country)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.CreateDate)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.Customer)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.CustomerContact)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.IsDone)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.IsSold)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.PhaseOneDescription)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.Seller)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.UploadedFiles)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.Website)
                    .Ignore(crml => crml.ZipCode)
                )
                .DefaultMappingFor<Customer>(m => m
                    .IndexName("customers")
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Activities)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Address)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.City)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Company)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Contacts)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Country)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.CreateDate)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Id)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.Projects)
                    .Ignore(cust => cust.ZipCode)
                )
        }

private static void CreateIndices(IElasticClient client)
    {
        client.Indices.Create("users",
            index => index
            .Map<ApplicationUser>(x => x.AutoMap())
        );

        client.Indices.Create("crmleads",
            index => index
            .Settings(se => se
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(analyzer => analyzer
                        .Custom("substring_analyzer", analyzerDescriptor => analyzerDescriptor
                            .Tokenizer("standard")
                            .Filters("lowercase", "substring")))
                    .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                        .NGram("substring", filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor
                            .MinGram(2)
                            .MaxGram(15))))
                .Setting("index.mapping.total_fields.limit", "2000"))
            .Map<CRMLead>(x => x
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(f => f.Name)
                        .Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(f => f.CVRNumber)
                        .Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))
                    .Boolean(t => t
                        .Name(f => f.IsConverted))
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(f => f.ContactPersonName)
                        .Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(f => f.ContactPersonEmail
                        ).Analyzer("substring_analyzer"))))
        );

        client.Indices.Create("customers",
            index => index
            .Settings(se => se
                    .Setting("index.mapping.total_fields.limit", "2000"))
            .Map<Customer>(x => x.AutoMap())
        );
    }
```

Technologies are:

1. Nest 7.10.1
2. .NET Core 3.1
3. Visual Studio 2019 - Community edition
4. ElasticSearch 7.10.1
5. Kibana 7.10.1

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After studying the index response (as @Milan Gatyas suggested) i found out that my tokenfilter NGram.MaxGram expected a difference of 1 but was 13

```
.NGram("substring", filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor
                            .MinGram(2)
                            .MaxGram(15))))
```

So to fix this I set the setting for max_ngram_diff to 15:

```
.Setting("index.max_ngram_diff", "15"))
```

Comment: Can you please investigate and share the content of CreateIndexResponse for the crmleads call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this i set the setting for max_ngram_diff to 15:

```
.Setting("index.max_ngram_diff", "15"))
```